# Commenting out in a bulk SQL developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

How to single comment out selected text in a bulk? I have 100+ lines of text that have to be commented out, single line each but idk how to do it, you can only comment out in bulk multiple lines that are treated like one entity using `/* text */`, but I want to transform:

```
a
b
c
```

into:

```
--a
--b 
--c
```

in a single command, anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highlight the lines and then use:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> or
- from the menu `Source > Toggle Line Comments`.